# Sugestão de melhoria de codigo, para abertura de varios arquivos csv em diretorios diferentes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ciência-de-dados

Boa noite amigos, um amigo me passou um código que ele estava desenvolvendo para que eu pudesse estudar, porem eu gostaria de ver uma melhor alternativa para a abertura de vários arquivos .csv, só que estão em diferentes pastas.

O código está imenso, creio que seja possível algo melhor com o loop for.

Tenho conhecimento básico em Python.

- Os diretórios estão divididos em 4 pastas, nomes de L1 - L2 - L3 - L4
- dentro de cada destas 4 pastas, tem algumas pastas com o formato de data. Ex: 03_02_20
- dentro destas pastas com as datas estão os arquivos.csv
- cada arquivo possui um código diferente no formato do nome, um numero 500 e alguma coisa. EX: L1_503_03_02_20.csv
  L1_505_03_02_20.csv
  ....
  L1_508_03_02_20.csv

Segue o código original abaixo:

```
# Importação dos CSVs
df = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df4 = pd.DataFrame()
df5 = pd.DataFrame()

for DateCSV in AnalysisDate:
    if Line == 'L4':
        df3 = pd.read_csv(
            DiretorioBase + "\\" + DateCSV + "\\" + Line + "_504_" + DateCSV + ".csv", sep=";")
        df3['workcenter'] = 3
        df1 = pd.read_csv(
            DiretorioBase + "\\" + DateCSV + "\\" + Line + "_502_" + DateCSV + ".csv", sep=";")
        df1['workcenter'] = 1
        df2 = pd.read_csv(
            DiretorioBase + "\\" + DateCSV + "\\" + Line + "_503_" + DateCSV + ".csv", sep=";")
        df2['workcenter'] = 2
        df5 = pd.read_csv(
            DiretorioBase + "\\" + DateCSV + "\\" + Line + "_506_" + DateCSV + ".csv", sep=";")
        df5['workcenter'] = 5
        df4 = pd.read_csv(
            DiretorioBase + "\\" + DateCSV + "\\" + Line + "_505_" + DateCSV + ".csv", sep=";")
        df4['workcenter'] = 4
    else:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(DiretorioBase + "\\" + DateCSV + "\\" + Line + "_505_" + DateCSV + ".csv", sep=";")
        df1['workcenter'] = 1
        df2 = pd.read_csv(DiretorioBase + "\\" + DateCSV + "\\" + Line + "_506_" + DateCSV + ".csv", sep=";")
        df2['workcenter'] = 2
        if not(Line == 'L2' and Mes == 2):
            df3 = pd.read_csv(DiretorioBase + "\\" + DateCSV + "\\" + Line + "_503_" + DateCSV + ".csv", sep=";")
            df3['workcenter'] = 3
        df4 = pd.read_csv(DiretorioBase + "\\" + DateCSV + "\\" + Line + "_507_" + DateCSV + ".csv", sep=";")
        df4['workcenter'] = 4
        df5 = pd.read_csv(DiretorioBase + "\\" + DateCSV + "\\" + Line + "_508_" + DateCSV + ".csv", sep=";")
        df5['workcenter'] = 5
    df = df.append(df1).append(df2).append(df3).append(df4).append(df5)

df['Line'] = Line
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow.

Não sei se consegui compreender bem seu problema, ainda sim trouxe uma solução:

```
import os
import pandas as pd


def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    for entry in listOfFile:
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)

    return allFiles


diretorio = r"C:\seu\diretório\base\nesta\variável"
files = getListOfFiles(diretorio)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, file in enumerate(files):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        df_x = pd.read(file, sep=";")
        df_x['workcenter'] = key
        df.append(df_x)
```

O que essa solução faz é:

1. A função lê todos as pastas e subpastas em um diretório e filtra apenas os arquivos, trazendo-os em uma lista.
2. Pega cada arquivo da lista retornada e, caso o arquivo termine com a extensão `.csv`, ele lê e salva em um dataframe temporário `df_x`.
3. Ao final, ele simplesmente adiciona esse dataframe temporário à um dataframe final `df`.

Não sei se ficou claro a solução, nem se atende suas espectativas.

Em caso negativo, comente aqui e vamos avaliando até chegarmos a melhor solução pra você.